# QField - Fields automatically filled when supposed NULL

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, error, qfield

Here is my issue :

On a QField project, I have few layers depending on from each other.
When "Compartment" is modified, then "ID" is modified and "Compartment value" receive a value (between 1 and 14).

When I add entities (points) one after the other, the form is working as expected.
But, after adding an entity, if I select another layer and select again my first layer to add another entity, then the fields are already filled.

I don't know if this problem is due to a mistake from me, or an error from QField.

There is no problem on QGIS.

Here is a video of the issue :
[Video](https://fromsmash.com/Video-020667)

And 2 test projects ; 1 on QFIELD, the other on QGIS.
[Project QField](https://fromsmash.com/Projet-QFIELD)
[Project QGIS](https://fromsmash.com/Projet-QGIS)

Can't add a video directly on the post, everything is updloaded on Smash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.
Developers from QField updated the application, something was wrong with the way widgets were functioning.